# How to get request locale in OGNL?

Tags: java, struts2, ognl

I want to know how to get request locale in OGNL?

For now I use

```
<s:set var="locale" value='#session.WW_TRANS_I18N_LOCALE?#session.WW_TRANS_I18N_LOCALE.toString():"zh_CN"'/>
```

This must assume that the initial value is "zh_CN".

So I need to know how to get request locale in OGNL.

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#request.locale
```

Answer (score 1):

`#request.locale` return java.util.Locale object

try

```
<s:if test="#request.locale.language=='en'">
  Current Locale is ENGLISH
</s:if>
<s:else test="#request.locale.language=='fr'">
  Current Locale is FRANCE
</s:else>
```